# How to automate commands in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

In my situation I am using Cygwin64 to connect to a remote SFTP server. I would like to have a script that opens cygwin and runs the sftp command and once I am connected to the server use the put command to send a file.

Comment: The default cygwin command interpreter is _bash_. You can write bash scripts.

Comment: in addition you can also write lftp scripts